# Zlib uncompress method not parsing an array of bytes from an image

Tags: c, png, zlib

Currently I'm trying to read the bytes from the `IDAT` chunk of a PNG image, in C. I am able to get all the other info, including the said array of bytes.

The problem arises whenever I try to decompress said array with zlib's `uncompress()` method.

```
[ ... ]

int decompress(Chunk * _chunk, Image * _image)
{
    uLongf compressedSize = _chunk->length;

    byte * uncompressedData = NULL;
    uLongf uncompressedSize = 0;

    int ret = uncompress(uncompressedData, &uncompressedSize, _chunk->data, compressedSize);

    if(ret != Z_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: failed to uncompress IDAT chunk data. ERR CODE: %d\n", ret);
        return -1;
    }

    [ ... ]
}
```

The `chunk` struct is defined as such:

```
typedef struct chunk
{

    uint32_t length;
    byte chunkType[4];

    byte *data;

} Chunk;
```

The `byte` type is just an `unsigned char`, and the `image` struct is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct image
{

    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;
  
    byte bitDepth;
    byte colorType;
    byte compression;
    byte filter;
    byte interlace;

} Image;
```

The test image's HEX representation is:

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52
00 00 00 11 00 00 00 12 04 03 00 00 00 4F D7 28
67 00 00 00 30 50 4C 54 45 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
80 00 80 80 00 00 00 80 80 00 80 00 80 80 80 80
80 C0 C0 C0 FF 00 00 00 FF 00 FF FF 00 00 00 FF
FF 00 FF 00 FF FF FF FF FF 7B 1F B1 C4 00 00 00
09 70 48 59 73 00 00 0E C4 00 00 0E C4 01 95 2B
0E 1B 00 00 00 28 49 44 41 54 08 D7 63 D8 0D 05
1B 18 36 30 00 01 FF FF FF 24 B1 FE FF FF C0 C0
40 0E 6B FF FF FF 20 73 48 60 C1 5D 0A 00 BB 1A
49 27 39 98 BC 6E 00 00 00 00 49 45 4E 44 AE 42
60 82
```

And the bytes of the `IDAT` chunk are:

```
08 D7 63 D8 0D 05 1B 18 36 30 00 01 FF FF FF 24 B1 FE FF FF C0 C0 40 0E 6B FF FF FF 20 73 48 60 C1 5D 0A 00 BB 1A 49 27
```

It must be noted that I'm not taking the CRC of the chunk as well; from my understanding it shouldn't be a problem.

Any idea as to why the `uncompress()` method is returning `Z_DATA_ERROR`?

Comment: what is the uncompress method, what does _chunk->data contain (are they the same bytes you said were the bytes of the IDAT chunk?)

Comment: actually I don't understand your question because "the bytes of the `IDAT` chunk are:" are obviously ***NOT*** the bytes of the `IDAT` chunk. We can see in the image file the IDAT chunk bytes are obviously `18 58 63 58 B1 62 05 00 03 F4 01 F9` (that's the next 0x0000000C bytes after the letters IDAT). I have no idea where you got your alleged IDAT chunk bytes from, but those are not the IDAT chunk bytes.

Comment: The hex representation is a mistake on my part: it seems the HEX editor I copied the values from misaligned quite a bit of data (I'm using a VSCode extension for HEX representation). I'll edit the post right now.

Comment: I updated the post with the correct data. Again, my apologies

Comment: and _chunk->data definitely contains those bytes? what about the uncompress method, what is it? you should probably post that method, which generates an error, in case it has a mistake - unlike the `Image` struct which is totally irrelevant to the question

Comment: _chunk->data contains said bytes; the `uncompress()` method is the one from the `zlib` C library, and [is defined here.](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/uncompr.c)

Edit: put the right link

Comment: think you mean [here](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/uncompr.c) - fair enough, I thought it was something you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not giving `uncompress()` anywhere to put the uncompressed data! `uncompressedData` cannot be `NULL`.